# Every second an unknown MAC address sends an ARP probe

Tags: ip, wireshark, mac-address, arp

I just inherited a network and found something I can't say I've seen before.

About every second (sometimes longer, sometimes shorter) a MAC address that I can't find anything about sends an ARP probe to an IP address that is not on my network.

Does anyone know what this could be?

The Wireshark image:

[image: WiresharkImage]

Comment: It’s coming from inside the house, no seriously, that traffic is only contained within your own network.

Comment: You could do binary search by cutting off parts of the network, in order to locate this device.

Comment: That MAC address's OUI would be TP-Link if it didn't have the "locally administered" bit set (the 2's place bit in the first byte). See if you have any TP-Link equipment, especially with the MAC address 0**c**:80:63:a0:c2:1b.